# JavaFX - Resizable with Java 10

Tags: java, javafx, java-10

I'm new in **Java 10**, I think I caught a bug.

Snippet:

```
stage.setResizable(false);
stage.setScene(new Scene(new Group()));
stage.show();
```

At **Java 8**: Give us a window with dimensions ***200x100***.

At **Java 10**: Give us a window with dimensions ***1x20***.

Use `FXML` with `BorderPane` and `prefWidth` / `prefHeight`  - did not fix problem.

> **Workaround**: do not use `setResizable`. Instead, use `setMinWidth`&`setMaxWidth` / `setMinHeight`&`setMaxHeight`.
>
> Tested on Linux with Java 10.0.2.

Sorry if *dublicate* or *existing* bug, I just wanted to share a discovery.

**Full code**:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        stage.setResizable(false);
        stage.setScene(new Scene(new Group()));
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not a bug report site. If you have a question then ask it. If you want to report a bug use https://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/.

Comment: And please don't forget to provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem (in the bug report as well as here :).

Comment: I'm running it on 8, 9 and 10 and I always get (1440.0, 759.0). It's probably configuration dependent.

Comment: From the first time - the problem may not appear.
I have a problem was detected after the third or fifth run, after changing the version.